# error identity_insert creating trigger sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to create a trigger that does not let you insert a registers if a constraint is not satisfied and also showing an error symbol. But when I create trigger sql-server tells me: 
You can only specify an explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
My code:

```
create trigger tri1
on table
for insert, update
as
 begin
  declare @code1 int 
  declare @code2 int
  declare @code3 varchar(20)
  declare @nif varchar(12)
  declare @date datetime
  declare @cost float
  insert into table values(@code1, @code2, @code3, @nif,@date, @cost)
  if (@cost not between 10 and 100)
  begin
   RAISERROR('Error', 16, 1);
   ROLLBACK;
  end
end
```

Comment: So, does `sanciones` has an identity column?. And, sorry, it was a rhetorical question, it does have an identity column and you are trying to insert an explicit value to it

Comment: Just use a check constraint for this.